# Asp.net MVC SelectList - Set Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I set the selected value on a select list.
For example, say i'm displaying an existing client and on the form it has a dropdown list for "Gender", I want "Male" to be selected (if that what was saved in the db) how do I do this?

When I'm building my model im doing something like

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
 var client= _clientService.FindById(id);
            var model = new ViewModels.Client()
            {
GenderId= client.GenderId,
GenderList= CreateGenderList(GenderId)
};
}

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateGenderList(int gId)
        {

            var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DomainObjects.Client.GenderList))
                .Cast<DomainObjects.Client.GenderList>()
                .Select(v => new SelectListItem { Text = v.ToString(), Value = ((int)v).ToString() });
//Need to set the selected value, how?


            return list.ToList();


        }
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: How are you generating the dropdown in the list? If the value of `GenderId` matches the value of one of your options, it will select it by default

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the additional `SelectListItem.Selected` property, and set this to true. For example:

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DomainObjects.Client.GenderList))
            .Cast<DomainObjects.Client.GenderList>()
            .Select(v => new SelectListItem {
    Text = v.ToString(),
    Value = ((int)v).ToString()});

var maleGenderItem = list.Single(x => x.Text == "Male");
maleGenderItem.Selected = true;
```

Comment: Holf, this does not actually update the existing list to mark selected = true

Answer (score 0):

This did it

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DomainObjects.Client.GenderList))
                .Cast<DomainObjects.Client.GenderList>()
                .Select(v => new SelectListItem { Text = v.ToString(), Value = ((int)v).ToString(), Selected = gName.ToString() == ((int)v).ToString() });

            return list.ToList();
```